# Converting equation to be used for ArrayFormula results in weird values

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if

I have the following (pretty ugly) equation for column Y:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(Q2),"NO VIDEO DATA",IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(I2,DEALS_RNG,COLUMN(DEALS!$G$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1,FALSE), "Likes"), IF(P2>=(VLOOKUP(I2,DEALS_RNG,COLUMN(DEALS!$F$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1,FALSE)), IF((R2<> W2),IF(R2,CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",M2)),IF(W2,CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",L2)),)),IF((R2* W2)>0,"COMPLETED",CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",Z2)))),IF(today() >= N2+K2,IF(X2,"PAID: MUST REPOST","NO PAYMENT: MUST REPOST"),IF(today() < N2+K2,CONCATENATE((N2+K2)-today()," days remaining"),))), IF(Q2>=(VLOOKUP(I2,DEALS_RNG,COLUMN(DEALS!$F$1)-COLUMN(DEALS!$A$1)+1,FALSE)), IF((R2<> W2),IF(R2,CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",M2)),IF(W2,CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",L2)),)),IF((R2* W2)>0,"COMPLETED",CONCATENATE("DUE: ", CONCATENATE("$",Z2)))),IF(today() >= N2+K2,IF(X2,"PAID: MUST REPOST","NO PAYMENT: MUST REPOST"),IF(today() < N2+K2,CONCATENATE((N2+K2)-today()," days remaining"),)))))
```

Not getting too into the full logic going on here, basically as it is now, it is functioning correctly when I drag it down rows:

[image: equation being used in column Y]

I changed my AND() to * and XOR() to <> as well as my cells from i.e. Q2 to Q2:Q, etc. But once in ArrayFormula the formula no longer works correctly and returns weird numbers (memory perhaps? idk):

[image: formula used in arrayformula]

Could anyone help me understand what is going on and how I could possibly resolve this?

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Understanding how the formula would work seems a bit complicated without a full visibility on the sample data since some of the formulas have columns which are not visible in the sample screenshot, so in regards to that, would it be okay if you could provide a test sheet/demo sheet/sample sheet for us to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISTEXT(Q2:Q), "NO VIDEO DATA",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(I2:I, DEALS_RNG, 7, ), "Likes"), 
 IF(P2:P>=(VLOOKUP(I2:I, DEALS_RNG, 6, )), 
 IF(R2:R<>W2:W, 
 IF(R2:R, "DUE: $"&M2:M,
 IF(W2:W, "DUE: $"&L2:L, )),
 IF((R2:R*W2:W)>0, "COMPLETED", "DUE: $"&Z2:Z)),
 IF(TODAY()>=(N2:N+K2:K), 
 IF(X2:X, "PAID: MUST REPOST", "NO PAYMENT: MUST REPOST"),
 IF(TODAY()<(N2:N+K2:K), (N2:N+K2:K)-TODAY()&" days remaining", ))), 
 IF(Q2:Q>=VLOOKUP(I2:I, DEALS_RNG, 6, ), 
 IF(R2:R<>W2:W, 
 IF(R2:R, "DUE: $"&M2:M,
 IF(W2:W, "DUE: $"&L2:L, )),
 IF((R2:R*W2:W)>0, "COMPLETED", "DUE: $"&Z2:Z)),
 IF(TODAY()>=(N2:N+K2:K),
 IF(X2:X, "PAID: MUST REPOST", "NO PAYMENT: MUST REPOST"),
 IF(TODAY()<(N2:N+K2:K), (N2:N+K2:K)-TODAY()&" days remaining", )))))))
```

Comment: You may have messed up the syntax somewhere: https://i.gyazo.com/6277837ac9cd56bc86b9f8354c61f567.png

It was showing the following error: "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

Comment: @dan maybe fixed. try now

Comment: ah yes, it's working now, thank you! I'll play around with it a bit to make sure the logic is still good. what was the problem with my original formula?

Comment: @dan CONCATENATE is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: ah understood, thanks. arrayformula really hates all these other functions haha. may i borrow your time for one more problem i just identified? i have a button in column C that enables one time payments by assigning true to everything in the helper column W.

and i'm seeing now that when i enable this button with the new updated equation using arrayformula, only the first cell in column W changes to true. how do i tell arrayformula to populate the rest of the column with true values as well?

Comment: with the cell ranges i know to convert them from i.e. C2 to C2:C, but what should I be doing when it's simply a single TRUE value that needs to populate down?

Comment: @dan try: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA({"Disable Help 1"; IF($C$8, S2:S=S2:S,S2:S)}),COUNTA(S:S),1)`

Comment: oh wow that's brilliant, thanks again. looks like everything is working correctly now